# How to select a bottom navigation menu programmatically from a `recyclerView` adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have `BottomNavigationView` in 'activity-home.xml' as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
                    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>
        
            </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_new"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_image"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:maxImageSize="56dp"
            app:tint="@null"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
            android:contentDescription="Show Categories" />
        
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
          android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
        
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Following is the 'mobile_navigation.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/mobile_navigation_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.OrdersFragment"
        android:label="@string/mobile_navigation_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.CartFragment"
        android:label="@string/mobile_navigation_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cart"/>

</navigation>
```

When I click each menu item from the bottom navigation it shows respective fragments and everything works perfectly as expected. Now I wanted to show/open 'CartFragment.kt', ('R.id.nav_cart') when I click a button that is in the `recyclerView` of the 'fragment_home'. I tried the following way but it didn't work as I expected.

Following is what I have in the `onBindViewHolder` of the adapter class of the 'fragment_home'

```
        holder.binding.btnGoToCart.setOnClickListener {
    val activity=context as HomeActivity
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,CartFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
```

Even though I tried as above I think, that's not how I am supposed to do it. All I wanted is to navigate to the bottom menu 'R.id.nav_cart' which should show 'CartFragment'

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following code in the adapter class of 'fragment_home'. When I hit the button, The bottom menu is highlighted as if it's selected but I don't know what's really happening since the fragment of which is not being shown properly. What I meant is, there is a `recyclerView` and a few `textView`s and `EditTexts` in the fragment but the `recyclerView` is not being shown, only other views are shown. Also, when I hit other bottom menu items, nothing happens at all except those menu items are highlighted.

```
            holder.binding.btnGoToCart.setOnClickListener {

                val activity=context as MainActivity

                var fragment:Fragment=CartFragment()
                val bottomNav: BottomNavigationView = context.findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
                bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.nav_cart -> {
                            fragment = CartFragment()
                        }
                    }
                    context.supportFragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .commit()
                    true
                }
                bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.nav_cart
            }
```

Comment: Can you make ask make it a bit detailed please ? is CardFragment is shown in one of the bottom navigation options or you want to navigate a totaly  new CardFragment that bottom navigation does not shown ?

Comment: My question is updated now, please check.

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear (to me). Show some screenshot or videos to help illustrate the issue.

Comment: @dominicoder My question is updated, I hope it's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: You added some layouts but the issue is still not clear. Again, pictures / videos would be worth 1000 words. However, I do notice you have `<navigation>` element but then you are manually setting fragment transactions when you should be using a nav controller. Read and follow the documentation carefully: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the link. Did you mean this line of code (`activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,CartFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()`)  by I am manually setting the fragment transaction, then, I was just trying how to accomplish my requirement. Now, about the issue... What I am trying to do is go to the fragment 'CartFragment', that is, select the bottom navigation menu ('R.id.nav_cart') when I click a button in the `recyclerView` of 'fragment_home'. I hope it's now clear.

Comment: @dominicoder maybe I should change my question to "How to select a bottom navigation menu programmatically from the `recyclerView` adapter?"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

Comment: @dominicoder That was awesome. If you add the content in the link as the answer then I can accept it as the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should change my question to "How to select a bottom navigation menu programmatically from the recyclerView adapter?"

Since you're using the navigation library, you would programmatically navigate to the desired destination. See [the example in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action#use-global-action).

In your case, something like:

```
holder.binding.btnGoToCart.setOnClickListener { view ->
    view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_cart)
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this, please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70134116/13935956