# RecyclerView inside nested scrollview loads slow initially

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `recyclerView` as below. This is inside a `fragment` which is the first screen that is displayed when the app launches. Before I add the `NestedScrollView`, the `recyclerView` used to load the data fast (or the recyclerView was displayed immediately). Now, after adding `NestedScrollView` it takes some time for the `recyclerView` to load the data (or to display the recyclerView).

I don't know whether the recyclerView is displayed late or the data is loaded slowly.

Note: Once it's shown, there is no issue when scrolling, items are loaded at normal speed on scroll. The issue is only at initial loading.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorOffWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/vp_deals"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_all_deals"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text="All Deals"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_home_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I do not have any issue with the touch or scroll.

Comment: if you have 50 items to be displayed in this recyclerView the onCreateViewHolder() method in the adapter will be called 50 times that's your problem cause the slow in the first initiate

Comment: Please set nestedScrollEnabled = false in java/kotlin file

Comment: I set it in `xml` and in `kotlin`, but didn't work.

Comment: Can someone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First: check the size of the images and reduce the size of the images

Second: You must disable nestedScrollingEnabled

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Answer (score -2):

This is a a common problem when you try to create recyclerview inside NestedScrollView cause the recycler view height not defined

try to set `recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

I think it will solve that problem

Also, it's better to define a certain height for recycler view when it is placed inside a nestedScrollView

Comment: I have `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in the `xml`

Comment: Then you need to define a certain height for recycler view